# Same set of Code Working in Eclipse IDE and not working in Command Line

Tags: java

The same code working in IDE, but not in Cmd Line. Here is my code. I cannot find what the error is?

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;

public class AppendingBuffer{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        StringBuilder sb;
        sb = new StringBuilder("abc");
        sb.append("def").reverse().insert(3, "---");
        System.out.println(sb);
    }
}
```

The two screen shots are here which shows the both IDE and Cmd line programs.

***Error In Command Line:***

```
E:\java\6>javac AppendingBuffer.java
AppendingBuffer.java:7: error: constructor StringBuilder in class StringBuilder
cannot be applied to given types;
                sb = new StringBuilder("abc");
                     ^
  required: no arguments
  found: String
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
AppendingBuffer.java:8: error: cannot find symbol
                sb.append("def").reverse().insert(3, "---");
                  ^
  symbol:   method append(String)
  location: variable sb of type StringBuilder
.\StringBuilder.java:5: error: constructor StringBuilder in class StringBuilder
cannot be applied to given types;
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("abc");
                                   ^
  required: no arguments
  found: String
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
.\StringBuilder.java:6: error: cannot find symbol
                sb.append("def").reverse().insert(3, "---");
                  ^
  symbol:   method append(String)
  location: variable sb of type StringBuilder
4 errors

E:\java\6>
```

[image: Java Command Line]
[image: Java IDE]

Comment: Can you post the error message separately again? It's hard to read.

Comment: What other files are in the directory you're running `javac` from?

Comment: well its working on my system

Comment: Can you please give the output of `java -version` from the CLI?

Comment: @UwePlonus Wild goose chase. The constructor is there in 5.0.

Comment: My wild guess is that at some point you wrote your own class named `StringBuilder`, and `javac` is picking up that because it's run with `C:\java\6` as the working dir. While Eclipse is using something else as the working dir (or generally has the internal compiler environment set up differently) so the `.class` file doesn't get picked up by the compiler.

Comment: Just FYI: [You don't need to import java.lang.*](http://www.cafeaulait.org/course/week4/31.html)

Comment: I was using command line for all programs.  It was working fine. I tried commenting all the codes and just print hello world.  which was working fine.  I updated my question with error in command line.

Comment: Try `System.out.println(StringBuilder.class)` and see what happened.

Comment: I'm upgrading my wild guess to "pretty certain". The error message would use the fully qualified name `java.lang.StringBuilder` if it was picking up the JDK class.

Comment: @millimoose:  You are absolutely right.  I am having another file named StringBuilder.java in the same directory which i was created before naming it.  Now after deleting it, it was working fine..  Thankyou.. thanks a lot.

Comment: @JavaBeginer Well, Reimeus already provided that as an answer, so he might as well get the accept.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Chances are you have another class `StringBuilder` on the classpath. Either rename the local source file or remove it completely before attempting to re-compile it.

Comment: In the same directory as the class `AppendingBuffer` there must be a class names `StringBuilder`.

Comment: @UwePlonus Or, more treacherously, in any directory set in the `CLASSPATH` environment variable, if the OP followed some outdated tutorial telling him to do so.

Comment: No, it must be in the path as the error message from the CLI shows `.\StringBuilder.java` as file name.